# Does weight loss and exercise make back pain go away?

Tags: back-pain

When I was younger I could play the guitar all day without back pain (muscular). I stoped playing and exercising for many years, this with associated weight gain. Now I wanted to play the same guitar again but back pain do not allow me to  it anymore (every 5 min I have to stop). I want to know if there is solution, and if exercise help. What is the best practice to strenght my back and be able to do what I used to do. There a detail, my sleep is not very good (few hours) and I can`t change this.

Comment: Weight loss and the right exercises for your particular back condition can make back pain go away.  Weight loss and the wrong exercises can aggravate your condition.  Only being able to tolerate 5 minute intervals of playing guitar is very limiting. First, find out what is wrong with your back and have a physical therapist set up specific exercises to correct the cause of your pain.  Then you can progress to cardio, flexibility and strength training.

Answer (score 2):

Being in shape helps prevent back pain. Being out of shape, overweight, and inactive all contribute to the problem.

I would lift weights at least two or three times a week, focusing on barbell squats and deadlifts, which are both tremendously helpful for strengthening the back. Yoga, going for a medium-long walk, or another form of stretching that you enjoy would be good to do on days you don't lift. It would be fine to add running, swimming, biking, rowing, or another form of cardio once or twice a week, to help lose weight. The primary problem is probably a weak back, however, which is best addressed with a barbell.

Comment: a word of caution about deadlifts and squats in case of back pain. The back and the spine are complex and whats good for one person might be bad for the other. Ive consulted a rehab specialist about my back and she told me to reduce weights on some exercises and forbidden doing some others, deadlifts among them. She also helped me establish correct for while doing squats. When in doubt, i recommend seeing a specialist.